# Light through slit casting circular shape

Tags: visible-light

This morning, my partner and I noticed a perfectly shaped semi circle of light on our bedroom wall. As the sun rose this quickly became a full circle. I could not see what was causing this shape so traced it with my hand back to a small vertical slit in out curtains. With a piece of paper I confirmed that the shape of the light patch was a slit right up by the curtains, but as I moved across the room it gradually morphed into a circle!

I thought it might be something to do with single slit diffraction, but I cannot find any exapmles that seems to create such a perfect circle and has no other visible artifacts.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide an image of the same for clarity?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_obscura although that talks about a pinhole, not a slit. Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/537201/123208 That's not quite a duplicate of your question, since it talks about a circular hole, not a slit, but it contains a lot of relevant and helpful information.

Comment: Here's a similar effect, but involving a square mirror, rather than a rectangular slit.

Comment: Please include the dimension of (a) the slit, and (b) the distance between the slit and the wall -- approximately.

Comment: The slit was approx 1 x 15mm, the circle was approx 50mm at a distance of approx 4.5m. Also, the flat part of the semi circle was on the top of the circle, disappearing as the sun rose.

Comment: You should [edit] that info into your question, don't bury it down here in the comments. But yes, that's definitely a camera obscura effect.